# Forcing other element's content to be moved by the same vertical amount

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, frontend

I have stumbled upon a frontend problem where I cannot figure out what the best approach is.
The simplified layout I need to achieve can be looked up here: https://jsfiddle.net/kw56sa84/

```css
content-block {
  min-height: 100px;
  background: #aaa;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.end-of-body-block {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #a00;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff;
  background: rgba(250, 180, 180, 0.9)
}

.footer {
  min-height: 300px;
  background: #0A152B;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-block">Some content</div>
    <div class="content-block">Some content</div>

    <div class="end-of-body-block">
      Some text here that can have into a dynamic height, and responsively height increases.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Links and other information that should be visible
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically what I have are content and footer and there is a block that should be 50% in the body and 50% in the footer, and have both element contents moved by a dynamic half-height of the connecting element. In the jsfiddle example, the footer content should have some sort of padding. The height of all elements is dynamic.

The main question I suppose here is - is it possible to achieve this with CSS (solution may include grids, flexboxes), or am I out of luck and should seek a JS solution?

**EDIT** Here you can see a simplified design that should be achieved:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not able to imagine what exactly you are looking for. could you add some image or grey wireframe?

Comment: Apologies, I guess I could have done a bit better at explaining. But so if it would be a fixed height, as [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v61djybo/8/) then I would just add margin-bottom: -halfHeight for the red element and then for footer padding-top: halfHeight. Will try to sketch it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of trial and error, I came up with an idea of how to solve this. It's a real hacky solution, but in my case it actually works, maybe someone else will find it useful.

So in my case the footer had an image background, thus making it more difficult to think of this, however.. solution here could be to simulate the same background as the other part where your element isn't.

To elaborate, instead of trying to move the other element's content, make it seem that it does so. I moved the red box to the footer instead, so it takes up the whole height it needs. Then add a pseudo (before) element as absolute to the red box's parent and make it full width and 50% of it's height. See here for example https://jsfiddle.net/co35svtd/4/

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #eee;
}

.content-block {
  min-height: 100px;
  background: #aaa;
  border: 1px solid;
}


.footer-block-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.end-of-body-block {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #a00;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff;
  background: rgba(250, 180, 180, 0.9);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 10;
}

.end-of-body-block:before {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.footer {
    min-height: 300px;
    background: #0A152B;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-block">Some content</div>
    <div class="content-block">Some content</div>
   
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-block-wrapper">
    <div class="end-of-body-block">
        Some text here that can have into a dynamic height, and responsively height increases.
      </div>
  </div>
      
    Links and other information that should be visible
  </div>
</div>
```

I know it's not the answer I was looking for, but this hack does the job for me.

Comment: After what I can offer you is to set « end-of-body-block » to his own container between content and footer and have a back ground linear gradient. It wont use position absolute.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that the footer contains an image as background. I couldn't possibly join it smoothly, especially when responsive. I guess I did a bad job explaining my issue. Or maybe I misunderstood you here.

Comment: Yeah if footer background is an image that is done indeed. Other it would have been a solution. Until you find your own that is good!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explication you want that class: "end-of-body-block" be positionned dynamicly between body and footer.

The basic idea is to remove the red box from the normal flow by using `position: absolute;` but by doing that, it is loosing basic position strucutre. So we fix it with parent with `position: relative;`. Which is classic move.

To do so, I added `position:relative;` in .content:

```
.content{
  position:relative;
}
```

And then I postionned absolute your red block as followed:

```
.end-of-body-block{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

### EDIT

JS to add dynamic padding on content and footer.

DEMO:

```js
var heightRed = document.getElementsByClassName('end-of-body-block')[0].offsetHeight;
heightRed = (heightRed / 2) + 2 + 'px';

var content = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0]
var footer = document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0]

content.style.paddingBottom = heightRed;
footer.style.paddingTop = heightRed;
```

```css
.content{
  position:relative;
}
.content-block {
  min-height: 100px;
  background: #aaa;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.end-of-body-block {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #a00;
  /*position: relative;
  transform: translateY(50%);*/
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff;
  background: rgba(250, 180, 180, 0.9);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}

.footer {
  min-height: 300px;
  background: #0A152B;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-block">Some content</div>
    <div class="content-block">Some content</div>

    <div class="end-of-body-block">
      Some text here that can have into a dynamic height, and responsively height increases.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Links and other information that should be visible
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't make the footer content to be moved down. It should be visible (have some padding-top). Also if the body content is longer, it will go under the red box in this case.

Comment: Question: will it be some other div between .content and .footer ? Will it be always the same text in red box ? And to answer, no matter how height will be your content, red box will stayed position.

Comment: No, it will differ. Thus, the height will vary as well.

Comment: the red box will stay in the middle between both like this no matter how large is the text in it or the content over, the problem is actualy the padding of footer. From the moment the red block wont have any fix height. We will need to add dynamic padding with js. you ok with that ?

Comment: The question is not really a matter of how to do it (I'm well aware how to achieve it with JS), but rather if it's possible to do it solely with CSS. Tried a lot of different ways, but maybe I missed something.

Comment: From the moment, that the block do not have any height fixed, I dont really see how to do it only css

Comment: @matiss.andersons I anyway finish the demo with js... in case you want to use that

Comment: Actually I just came up with another idea. But thanks! I will post my solution soon.